# UIWebview respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a custom `UITableviewCell` with `UIWebview` which shows the error message

> respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated instance

while poping a new `viewController`.

Here is my code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.exhibitorDetailTbleVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[SpeakerDescriptionTableCell class]]) {
         SpeakerDescriptionTableCell *cellTable = [self.exhibitorDetailTbleVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];
         [cellTable.descriptionWebView setDelegate:nil]; 
         cellTable.descriptionWebView = nil; 
         [cellTable.descriptionWebView stopLoading];
     }
```

Still showing the error, any idea where i am doing wrong.

Comment: your are nilling the cellTable.descriptionWebView = nil. then calling a method on it.how should he respond :)

Comment: my bad, line misplacement. If i remove  cellTable.descriptionWebView = nil; or drag down it ... nothing is working

Comment: then the problem is something else. because after niling it will not respond to any method.

Comment: issue is in webview as per instrument description . https://i.stack.imgur.com/XozXs.png